# How to turn iPhone style table view into iPad style table view (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I apologise in advance if this is a really simple thing to do, but I have searched and searched for answers and cannot find anything anywhere.

I have made an iPhone app that has a similar sort of interface to the built-in iPhone Mail app. It has a table view, and when you tap on an item it segues to the corresponding document. When I build it for iPadOS it works in the same way, as you would expect.

But this isn't how iPad apps are supposed to look. I want my app to look like the Mail app does when running on an iPad, with the table view to the left of the content when in landscape, and the ability to slide it in when in portrait. I simply have no idea how to even get started though. If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: If you are targeting iOS (and iPadOS) 14, I suggest you check out the sessions from WWDC 2020 on the improvements Apple did to `UISplitViewController`. Specifically, how it uses a Primary/Secondary versus Compact VCs. (For iPad, it also has a Primary as slide out and a Supplementary VC for a three panel.)

Comment: Thank you! I've never heard of the UISplitViewController, and just knowing its name is a huge help. I'll go and look for those WWDC sessions now. Thanks again!!